# Using different font sizes and double spacing to be same as in MS Word

Tags: spacing, fontsize

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,usenames,dvipsnames]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=4cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,times,etoolbox,titlesec,color,fancyhdr,anyfontsize,setspace,shadowtext,lipsum}

\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChTitleUpperCase


\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\date{}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\doublespacing


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}


    \textcolor{Sepia}{ % Red font color
\textsc{\Large XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX }\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Title line 1
\textsc{\Large xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    }\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Title line 2
\textsc{\Large xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\[0.5\baselineskip]
\textsc{\Large xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}% Title line 3
    }
    
    \rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.4pt} 
    

        \large
\textcolor{Mahogany}{        
        xxxxxxxxxxxx}
        
\textcolor{Mahogany}{\textsc{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}}

\textcolor{Mahogany}{ xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}

\textcolor{Sepia}{xxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\
   %     \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{university}
        \large
\textcolor{Sepia}{
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
   

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt} % Thin horizontal rule
    
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} % Thick horizontal rule
            
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}

    \vspace{0.05\textheight}
%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

    \textcolor{Black}{ % Red font color
{\huge xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Title line 1
{\huge xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Title line 2
{\huge xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}\\[0.5\baselineskip] 
{\huge xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
    }
    
    \rule{0.3\textwidth}{0.4pt} 
    
    \vspace{2pt}

        \Large
\textcolor{Black}{        
        xxxxxxxxxxxx}
        
\textcolor{Black}{\textsc{\textbf{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}}}

\textcolor{Black}{xxxxxxxxxxxx}

            
    \end{center}

\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  {\Large xxxxxxxxx}\\
\end{tabular}%
\hspace*{5.5cm}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  {\Large xxxxxx}
\end{tabular}%
\hspace*{1cm}


\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgement}

\lipsum[1] 

{
\cleardoublepage% Move to first page of new chapter
\let\clearpage\relax% Don't allow page break
\begin{center}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\ 

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\

yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
\end{center}


\chapter*{Abstract}
}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Q1) In the above example, I would like to convert the text in the first two pages to have font size =16 and double spacing, which is exactly the same font size 16 and double spacing in MS Word. I'm not sure how to use \fontsize{}{} and decide what values to be used inside {}{} to have that.

I've seen that giving font sizes as \large, \Large have different sizes based on whether we use \documentclass[12] or \documentclass[11] etc. and I can't understand how to get font size =16 and double spacing exactly.

Q2) I also want to clarify whether the Times font that I have used by using the \usepackage{times} and the double spacing I have got by the \doublespacing command are exactly same as those in MS word?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please reformat your LaTeX code so that it's only one block, and remove everything that isn't necessary to show your problem.

Comment: The font loaded by the 'times' package is called Nimbus Roman L. While that font *could* be used in Word, it's not exactly the same font as Microsoft's proprietary "Times New Roman" that comes with Windows/Office if that's what you mean, though they are very similar. Compare the italic z's for example. TeX Gyre Termes (newtxtext, newtxmath packages) is another option, IMHO *better* than MS's.

Comment: If you want to use Microsoft's "Times New Roman" for "reasons", you'd have to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with the fontspec package. I don't have that font or Word installed, so I can't help you emulate it exactly. Open license beats proprietary any day of the week IMHO.

Comment: you are not using times at all, you load the times package along with many other unused packages but change the font to latin modern `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well — you should never use explicit font sizes in LaTeX; that should be a task for the document class designer to select a coherent set of fonts.

But you can have rope to hang yourself if you want. Times New Roman from Word is proprietary, so in my example below, I use one of the clones available in TeXLive. If you own an MS Word license, you can use the real font with LuaLaTeX, but that's another story...

The solution here will not give *exactly* what MS Word will render. For that, you have to use MS Word, sorry. This kind of usage is, at best, a stretch of LaTeX philosophy...

The low-level size-changing command is `\fontsize{A}{B}`, which sets the font at A points and a normal baseline distance at B point. Normally you want B to be a bit more than A, so the lines will not run one over the other. Notice that this will not adjust several of the distances and sizes that should be adjusted when changing font size...

Plus, I use `setspace` for double line spacing (eeek...). So here is the ugliest MWE (notice that this one *is* minimal) I have ever posted...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% times new roman "clone"
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just to generate dummy text
\begin{document}
\doublespace

% This is a very bad design, but...

{\fontsize{24}{26}\selectfont This is 24 points; be sure to end the paragraph before closing the group or changing font again. Notice that this will not work nicely with a \emph{lot} of things.

}% blank line to end paragraph


{\fontsize{20}{22}\selectfont This is 20 points; be sure to end the paragraph before closing the group or changing font again. Notice that this will not work nicely with a \emph{lot} of things.

}% blank line to end paragraph

{\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont This is 16 points; be sure to end the paragraph before closing the group or changing font again. Notice that this will not work nicely with a \emph{lot} of things.

}
\end{document}
```

[image: ugly looking document]

Comment: Thank you very much @Rmano This is a great help! I'm in real trouble if I can't change the font sizes in my document now, so thanks again :)